# How to stop reactive form validators to not trigger on OnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I am trying to validate my form fields but the Validators are showing the error message from the time page is loaded. This is happening if I am not using Angular Material `mat-form-field`. In `mat-form-field` this issue is not occurring. Can anyone suggest me how can I get rid of this issue ?

This [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-retgxj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the working example of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop it on OnInit.

A common way to deal with it is to update the condition on the visibility of the error message by displaying it only if the field has been touched :

```html
  <small *ngIf="Field1.errors?.required && Field1.touched">Error1</small>
```

Comment: well this solution is known to me but I was hoping if there's any better approach